# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is always empty

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Threads I searched

- [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings count 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034692/configurationmanager-appsettings-count-0)
- [Reading settings from app.config or web.config in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net)
- [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469384/configurationmanager-appsettings-is-empty?r=SearchResults&s=1|82.6644)
- [WPF configurationmanager.appsettings collection is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984079/wpf-configurationmanager-appsettings-collection-is-empty)

My application is a .NET Core 3.1 app so I added the library `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` via NuGet to my project. My root folder contains a `Web.Config` with the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"  />
        <httpRuntime  />
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- Folder of LogParser job-configurations -->
        <add key="JobFolder" value="App_Data/jobs"/>
        <!-- Background task execution interval in seconds -->
        <add key="Interval" value="5"/>
        <!-- Message offset in seconds. Reads older messages to circumvent log4net timestamp bug -->
        <add key="Offset" value="7200"/>
        <!-- Caching duration for hash MemoryCache in seconds. Default is 604800 (7 days) -->
        <add key="Caching" value="604800"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

However, when I access `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]` it's always empty. Also, `Configurationmanager.AppSettings.AllKeys` is empty and the count is 0, as if it's not being parsed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure you don't mean to have an appSettings.json file?

Comment: I had one, yes but https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8 said that I need a .config file. Do I need an appSettings.json file instead?

Comment: Dot net core does not use `.config` files and configuration manager

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, I read that, but it's supported when adding it as a NuGet package (at least I found out through Google). Is there another way to get the contents?

Comment: @Nkosi It may not be supported but works fine, must be something else. I know because I have used that in many applications personally.

Comment: @TanveerBadar you are correct. I misspoke. It does not use it by default any more. You have to explicitly add/reference it to use it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, https://stackoverflow.com/users/392957/tony-abrams pointed me in the right direction.

So basically, I need an `appsettings.json` file (even if the Internet told me otherwise) and I defined it like this

```
{
    "JobFolder": "App_Data/jobs",
    "Interval": 5,
    "Offset": 7200,
    "Caching": 604800
}
```

Then, in the class where I need this I added a new constructor argument `IConfiguration configuration` which is already registered in the DI container, so no further action needed there.

Then, when I want to access the value, I can simply do `_configuration.GetValue<string>("JobFolder")` and have the value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to add for anyone who comes here doesn't have the option to use the appsettings.json....

For me this problem manifest itself inside a UnitTest project.  ConfigurationManager expects a file named ASSEMBLYNAME.dll.config, but the Unit Tests in .net core run under the name "testhost" so it looks for testhost.dll.config.  Therefore you need to rename the generated config file to match what ConfigurationManager is looking for.

In your csproj file, add a build step like such...

```
<Target Name="CopyAppConfig" AfterTargets="Build" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <CreateItem Include="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll.config">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FilesToCopy"/>
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)testhost.dll.config" />
</Target>
```

Solution came from 
https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/348

Comment: If using Rider or, presumably, Resharper's test runner inside VS, you will also need the following: `<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)ReSharperTestRunner.dll.config" />`

If this doesn't work, step into `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and take a look at `s_configSystem._completeConfigRecord.ConfigContext` and find the `ExePath` variable.

Comment: In your debugger, you can use   `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` to determine what the expected name will be. For me, it looked like this (shortened): `"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\..\ReSharperTestRunner.dll"` That meant my .config file needed to be named `ReSharperTestRunner.dll.config`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when migrating `asp` app from `.net 4.x` to `.net core 3.1`. To preserve functionality relying on `ConfigurationManager` I also installed `nuget` package [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/), but both `ConnectionStrings` and `AppSettings` were empty.

At the moment I cannot use `appsettings.json`, so I had to move my settings from `web.config` to `app.config`. It seems like
`.net core` version of `ConfigurationManager` [works only with `app.config`](https://rimdev.io/what-works-and-what-doesnt-with-configurationmanager-appsettings-using-aspnetcore31/).

Comment: This is works, but is not the answer I wanted.